# How to use left join yii2 search model

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have two tables named as user,userdetails. In user table the columns are id,name,value. In userdetails table the columns are id,userid,value.

I am using yii2 grid view to display the data. I used left join to get name,value. My question is how to use if condition in query because, in userdetails table if there is no value for value column means i need to take a value from user table. If there is a value for value column means, i need to take a value from userdetails table.

```
$query = TerminalPossetting::find()->select(['a.id','a.name','a.value'])
                                ->from('user as a')
                                ->leftJoin('userdetails as b','a.id=b.userid');
```

Here i got a value from user table only. If there is a value in userdatils tables means then that value will disply in a grid. Otherwise the value from user table will diaply on a grid.

How to do this?